# Error when trying to implement Multisig wallet

Tags: contract-development, truffle, metamask, multisignature

When we try to send ether transaction execution in multisig got error in signing.

**Error: Invalid signature value.**

while calling contract execute function in solidity code

**Error: invalid address at inputAddressFormatter.**

We are using Christian Lundkvist's Simple MultiSig Wallet contract. 
https://medium.com/@ChrisLundkvist/exploring-simpler-ethereum-multisig-contracts-b71020c19037

**Github Link :- https://github.com/unchained-capital/ethereum-multisig**

Above code is Transfered using Metamask.

Comment: in my opinion this contract is overly complex and broken